# Twitter rate limit

Tags: twitter, twitter-feed

I'm trying to use this:

https://twitter.com/account/rate_limit_status.xml

to check that i'm not going over the rate limiting on twitter. Problem is i'm making calls but the remaining-hits param does not seem to be reducing by as much as i'm calling:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<hash>
<reset-time-in-seconds type="integer">1281858712</reset-time-in-seconds> 
<reset-time type="datetime">2010-08-15T07:51:52+00:00</reset-time> 
<remaining-hits type="integer">146</remaining-hits> 
<hourly-limit type="integer">150</hourly-limit> 
</hash>
```

I'm just making calls that don't require authentication and I've read this bit in the documentation:

*Requires Authentication (about authentication):
true, to determine a user's rate limit status
false, to determine the requesting IP's rate limit status*

(https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting)

So do I need to set false somewhere in my call? I'm not an authenticated user so the only limits I have are the current limit on the ip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. If you don't use authentication then "false" is supposed automatically.

Are you sure that you are making calls that are rate limited:

> The REST API does user and IP-based
>   rate limiting. Authenticated API calls
>   are measure against the authenticating
>   user's rate limit. Unauthenticated
>   calls are deducted from the calling
>   hosts IP address allowance.
>
> Rate limits are applied to methods
>   that request information with the HTTP
>   GET command. Generally API methods
>   that use HTTP POST to submit data to
>   Twitter are not rate limited, however
>   some methods are being rate limited
>   now. **Every method in the API
>   documentation explains if it is rate
>   limited or not.**